# debian64 wheezy with fglrx 1:12-1-2 shows different server and client glx string

Tags: debian, wine, fglrx

I'm trying to get wine compiled with debian64 wheezy; however, the configure script shows at the end:

```
configure: WARNING: No OpenGL library found on this system.
OpenGL and Direct3D won't be supported.
```

This irks me immensely, since I planned to play games under wine... I'm using fglrx packaged for debian (from non-free section), not the download from AMD site.

From `config.log`:

```
configure:8770: checking for -lGL
configure:8795: gcc -m32 -o conftest -g -O2    conftest.c -lGL  -lXext -lX11 -lm >&5
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../libGL.so when searching for -lGL
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libGL.so when searching for -lGL
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
```

I've dug around a bit and found some hints and it seems that my compiler somehow can't find the proper libraries.

Also, I've found that my server and client glx string differ, even though I have fglrx installed:

```
# glxinfo | grep string
server glx vendor string: ATI
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
OpenGL vendor string: ATI Technologies Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: ATI FirePro V4800 (FireGL) Graphics Adapter
OpenGL version string: 1.4 (2.1 (4.2.11399 Compatibility Profile Context FireGL))
```

Those might not be related, it's just my hunch I put those together.

Any pointers are welcome.

Thank you.